# C: Store a list of ints in Array

Tags: c

What i'm trying to solve here is print a list of prime numbers into an array. I'm kinda fresh to C and the following code is what I have so far, it does not seem to accomplish what I am looking for which a list of prime numbers.

```
#inlude <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
int i, j, arr[40]

for (i=2; i<40; i++){
  for (j=1; j<i; j++) {
     if (i%j == 0){
     arr[i] = 0;
     }
     else 
        arr[i] = i;
  }
   printf("%d\n", arr[i]);
 }
}
```

This code prints a list 0 instead of primes

Comment: use your debugger. that's what it is there for!

Comment: Use `;` after `int i, j, arr[40]` and initialize array elements by `0`.

Comment: array index start with `0` but here you  start it with `i=2`. Also first solve some syntax error in your code like `#inlude <stdio.h>` should `#include <stdio.h>`. And missing `;` after `int i, j, arr[40]`.

Comment: It doesn't print a list of zeros.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
int i, j, arr[40]; // you forgot ';' here
int flg =0;  // use an additional flag

for (i=2; i<40; i++)
  {
    for (j=2; j<i; j++)  // don't start from j=1? every number is divisable by 1
    {
       if (i%j == 0) flg=1;  // flage raises whenever divisor found
    }
    if(flg == 0) arr[i]=i; // no divisor ==> prime number
    else arr[i] =0;  // there are divisors ==> not prime number

    flg = 0;  // reset flag to use in next iteration, next number

    printf("%d\n", arr[i]);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you posted code which is not original one. It contains many syntax error.
correct first it.

1. `#inlude <stdio.h>` must be `#include <stdio.h>`
2. put `;` after `int i, j, arr[40]`
3. Array index must start with `0` but here you initialize array with `i=2`.

Also use of two for loop is looks bad codding style instead you can use one function which return the status of number if it's prime number or not. like

```
#include <stdio.h>

int prime(int n){
    int j;
    for (j=2;j<=n/2;j++)
        if((n%j)==0)
            return 0;
   return 1;
}
void main(){
    int i,p,index, arr[40];
    for (i=2;index=0,i<=40;i++,index++)
    {
        p=prime(i);
        if(p==1)
          arr[index]=i;
        else
         arr[index]=0;


         printf ("%d\n", arr[index]);
    }
}
```

Comment: How would i create a 10x10 table using the content in the array?

Comment: i did't understand you mean by `array[10][10]`?

Comment: After you store the primes in the array i need to create a 10x10 table

Comment: @nyabuto really still not getting you. why you require 10x10 table?

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you want:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
int i, j, arr[40]={0};

for (i=2; i<40; i++){
    for (j=2; j<i; j++) {

        if (i%j == 0){
            arr[i] = 0;
            break;
        }

        arr[i] = i;
    }

}
for(i = 1; i < 40; i++ )
    printf("%d\n", arr[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the code you've given doesn't compile. You've written `inlude` instead of `include` on the first line, and your declaration of `i`, `j`, and `arr` needs a `;` at the end of the line.

With that taken care of, the code compiles, but it doesn't produce 0s - it produces

```
0
3
4
5
6
...
```

etc. Your inner loop sets `arr[i]` at every iteration, so your `printf` will only see what it was set to that last time through the loop. The last time through the loop, you had `j`=`i-1`, which will only satisfy your `if` when `i` = 2 (so `j` = 1)

To fix this you need to do two things:

Break out of the inner loop the first time you find a divisor, to make sure you don't overwrite the `0` that you write when you do find a divisor.

Start the inner loop from `j=2` instead of `j=1`. Remember `1` is a divisor for primes (as well as every other integer), so if you start the loop from 1, all of the numbers will fail your test